# Multiplying 2D Matrices to get a 3D Matrix in R

Tags: r

so I have a code that I have been trying to use to get a 2x2x6848 3D matrix. But I have been having some trouble on getting the loop to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
        > t2
           [1] 6847

        > dim(A)
           [1] 2 2
        > dim(F4)
           [1] 6848    2
        > dim(backward2)
            [1] 6848    2
        > dim(D)
             [1] 6848    2

         x <- array(, dim=c(6848, 2,2 ))
         t2<- t-1
         for (i in 1:t2){
         x[i,,]=A*(t(F4[t2,])%*%(backward2[t2+1,]*D[t2+1,])))}
```

And I think it has something to do with this:

```
           (A*(t(F4[1,])))
           Error in A * (t(F4[1, ])) : non-conformable arrays
```

Comment: What trouble are you getting? I guess that you used `t2` instead of `i` as indices in the loop and you have an extra `)` at the end: `A*(t(F4[i,])%*%(backward2[i+1,]*D[i+1,]))`

Comment: Hi Nicola, thanks for the response. You're right, I fixed that but I am still getting error: > for (i in 1:t2){
+  x[i,,]=(A*(t(F4[i,])%*%(backward2[i+1,]*D[i+1,])))}
Error in A * (t(F4[i, ]) %*% (backward2[i + 1, ] * D[i + 1, ])) : 
  non-conformable arrays

Comment: Don't get what you are trying to calculate, but this solve the issue: `for (i in 1:t2) x[i,,]=A*c((t(F4[i,])%*%(backward2[i+1,]*D[i+1,])))`. If it produces the result you are trying to get, I don't know.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! Not sure why you had to 'combine' the latter half of that loop. But it did work.

Comment: The result of `t(F4[i,])%*%(backward2[i+1,]*D[i+1,])` is a 1x1 matrix, which cannot be multiplied to `A`, a 2x2 matrix. By putting `c` on top of it, you strip the `dim` attribute and it becomes a standard vector of length one which can be multiplied to any matrix.